# Redirect to a new page by using the same url with url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a page "www.test.com/info.php". 
I would like to redirect to google page after it automatically refresh by using the same URL as stated above with google url parameter added.For example: "www.test.com/info.php?URL=google". Does anyone know how to perform this?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You can set Header on info.php like

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```